# Getting 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

Tags: jqgrid

Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $("#Employee-grid-array").jqGrid({
                datatype: "xml",
                mtype: 'json',
                rowNum: 1,
                url:'/DebitCredit/Index',
                rowList: [1, 2, 4, 5, 10],
                colNames: ['Account', 'Tranaction No', 'Transaction Date', 'Status', 'Landfill Site', 'Transaction Amount', 'Vat Amount', 'Weight', 'Remarks'
                 , 'Created by', 'Created Date'],
                colModel: [
                      { name: 'Account_No', index: 'Account_No', width: 100,  editable: true },
                      { name: 'Tran_No', index: 'Tran_No', width: 100,  editable: true },
                      { name: 'Tran_Date', index: 'Tran_Date', width: 150,  editable: true },
                      { name: 'Status_QC', index: 'Status_QC', width: 50  },
                      { name: 'Landfill_Site_ID', index: 'Landfill_Site_ID', width: 100,  editable: true },
                      { name: 'Tran_Amount', index: 'Tran_Amount', width: 100,  editable: true },
                      { name: 'Vat_Amount', index: 'Vat_Amount', width: 100,  editable: true },
                      { name: 'Weight', index: 'Weight', width: 70,  editable: true },
                      { name: 'Remarks', index: 'Remarks', width: 70,  editable: true },
                      { name: 'Created_By', index: 'Created_By', width: 100  },
                       { name: 'Created_Date', index: 'Created_Date', width: 100  },
                ],
                pager: jQuery('#pagernav'),
                multiselect: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                shrinkToFit: false
            }).navGrid('#pagernav', { edit: true, add: true, del: true },
        // Edit options
            {
                savekey: [true, 13],
                reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                jqModal: false,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                url: "/DebitCredit/Edit",
                closeAfterSubmit: true,
                afterSubmit: function () {
                    $("#Employee-grid-array").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')
                }
            },
        // Add options
             {
                 url: '/DebitCredit/Create', closeAfterAdd: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true
             },
        // Delete options
               {
                   url: '/DebitCredit/Remove',
                   jqModal: false,
                   serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
                     
                       return { id: postdata.Tran_No,test:"test" }; // the body MUST be empty in DELETE HTTP requests
                   },

                   afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                       var rowdata = $('#Employee-grid-array').getRowData(postdata.Account_No);
                       return { Name: postdata.Tran_No, test: "test" };

                   }
               },
               {
                 
                   closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true,
                   closeAfterSearch: true
               }
               );
</script>
```

Getting below error after clicking
submit in edit popup(on Edit options afterSubmit line)

> Unhandled exception at line 602, column 21 in "Link"
>
> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you are missing your jquery and/or jquery grid declarations. I took your code and put this above your script

```
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.5.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.5.2/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
```

and it didn't throw your error -- i didn't try to wire up anything. For best practices, its recommended you put css in  and javascript at bottom of body