# Getting 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

Tags: jqgrid

First of all, yes I know that there is almost the same question on Stackoverflow, but i still can't get it to work. Even with the provided solution, which I found there:
[Getting 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112747/getting-0x800a01b6-javascript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-o)

- I want to get Data into my Grid.
- I am using *Visual Studio 2017*.

**Problem:**
When I try to run the program I get this error:

> Unhandled exception at line 56, column 13 in "Link"
>
> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

**index.cshtml:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>FlexDatenportal</title>
    <link rel="icon" href=".\icon.png">
    <link href="~/styles/styles`enter code here`heet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>

    <script type=text/javascript>
        $

(function () {
                "use strict";
                $("#grid").jqGrid({
                    colModel: [
                    { key: true, name: 'ID', index: 'ID'},
                    { name: "Vorname" },
                    { name: "Nachname" }
                ],
                data: [
                    { Vorname: "Angelk", Nachname: "Merkel" },
                    { Vorname: "Vladimir", Nachname: "Putin" },
                    { Vorname: "David", Nachname: "Cameron" },
                    { Vorname: "Barack", Nachname: "Obama" },
                    { Vorname: "François", Nachname: "Hollande" }
                ]
                });
    
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <a href=".\index.html"><img class="flexLogo" src="~/styles/Bilder/flexLogo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
        <h1 class="Titel">Datenportal</h1>
        <p class="UsernameTag">username</p>
        <img class="profileimg" src="~/styles/Bilder/profileimage.jpg" alt="profileimg">
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <div class="Daten">
            <p class="DatenHeadline">Daten</p>

            <table id="grid"></table>         
            
            <div class="inputAButton row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="in1" maxlength="20">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="in2" maxlength="20">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="in3" maxlength="20">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="in4" maxlength="20">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" id="AddButton" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="Signed">by Patrick Korb</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**HomeController.cs:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MyFirstWebApp.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Net;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace MyFirstWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        /***Connection***/
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("myConnectionString"));
        PatrickTestDBEntities db = new PatrickTestDBEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }
        
        public JsonResult GetMitarbeiter()
        {
            var testQuery = (from a in db.tbl_PatricksMitarbeiter
                             select new
                             {
                                 a.ID,
                                 a.Vorname,
                                 a.Nachname
                             }).Distinct();

            return Json(testQuery);
        }
        
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried Oleg's free jqGrid.I pretty much copied Oleg's Javascript from https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html  and changed the GetMitarbeiter method in the Controller.

Let me know if you need any more detail. (my first question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please write *always* which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

In any way the list of JavaScript files and the order of files, which you use

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/grid.locale-en.js"></script>   
<script src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
```

is wrong.

You should first include jQuery (for example, `jquery-1.11.0.min.js`) and then all jQuery plugins: jQuery UI (`jquery-ui.min.js`) and jqGrid. It's required additionally to include jQuery UI CSS additionally to JS file.

If you use old version of jqGrid (or commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS) then you should include `grid.locale-en.js` before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. If you use free jqGrid fork then you don't need to include `grid.locale-en.js` because English US locale in included in `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` by default.

It's wrong to include **both** minimized (`jquery.jqGrid.min.js`) and non-minimized (`jquery.jqGrid.js` or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js`) JavaScript code of jqGrid. You should use **only one** version of jqGrid.

If you use Bootstrap CSS on your page, then you should consider to use jqGrid with Bootstrap options too. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap) for example. You can load all free jqGrid files from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) or alternatively to use free jqGrid from NuGet package [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid) or npm package (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid)).

**UPDATED** The error in your project is independent from jqGrid. You included in `Index.cshtml` **the whole** HTML code of the page starting with `<!DOCTYPE html>`. ASP.NET MVC combines `"~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"` by default with the content of `Index.cshtml` and you get absolutely wrong HTML page, where the content of `Index.cshtml` will be placed in the `<body>` of `_Layout.cshtml`.

You can fix the problem by adding

```cs
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

at the beginning of `Index.cshtml` (before the line `<!DOCTYPE html>`).

Comment: I tried your sequence of scripts, which didn't work. I've tried some different ones as well but I can't get it to work. I am using Guriddo jqGrid js. Should I update the code above to what I currently use?

Comment: No matter which script you use. If you continue with Guriddo you my need to add these jqGrid options to the script: `serializeGridData: function (postData) {  return JSON.stringify(postData);  }, ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },` Check this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/jqgrid-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/)

Comment: @TonyTomov I've tried your solution and added those jqGrid optiions, but unfortunately the same error occurs. Is your code the only thing I need to add or is there more?

Comment: @Pui: The error "Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'" means typically that you don't included jqGrid JavaScript file at all (wrong path, for example) or you included it *before* jQuery and registering of jqGrid method (in `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`) failed. In any way you have to decide which fork of jqGrid you plan to use: commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)), which develop Tony Tomov or [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop. You should append your question with the current HTML/JS code.

Comment: @Pui Since you use Guriddo jqGrid JS, be a sure that everything with installation [described here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/#installation) is done. To help - create the grid like described in the docs without using VS and check if it works

Comment: I will delete everything again and try "free jqGrid" and hope that works, thanks for the help

Comment: @Pui: If you want to try free jqGrid, I'd recommend you to load all files from CDN. Look at [the code](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data_code) and https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dmx68uzm/18/. If you new in jqGrid then reading of [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) is strictly recommended.

Comment: @Oleg I tried free jqGrid.. Same problem- updated my question

Comment: @Pui: I suppose you repeat the same error all time and the origin of the error is outside of the code, which you post. You can create the demo Visual Studio project and share it somewhere. If you would have problems with upload, than you can sent it me via email: oleg.kiriljuk@ok-soft-gmbh.com. I suppose that I will see the problem immediately after I'll open the Visual Studio project.

Comment: @Oleg can I send it via Google Drive?

Comment: @Pui: It doesn't matter for me. You can just sent me URL where I can download the project (zip or 7z file) or the project itself. You should remove all dll or other binaries from the zip/7z file. The files will be resorted/created by Visual Studio automatically. In the case the project will be very small.

Comment: @Oleg I shared it with your email. You should be able to get it on Google Drive.

Comment: @Pui: I get the project. The error is very simple. I described it in **UPDATED** part of my answer. You can add `@{ Layout = null; }` at the beginning of `Index.cshtml` to fix the problem. By the way, if you want to share Visual Studio Project with other people you should **remove** `packages` folder from the root and the folders `bin` and `obj`. All required files will be restored by Visual Studio automatically. It reduces dramatically the size of the solution, which you need to share with other people. You should zip the resulting files in one archive.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Guriddo jqGrid](http://guriddo.net/) Please check the detailed installation [documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/#installation)